# How to code a Website with div's that have the image as well as margins and have the div's go to the edge

Tags: css, html

I am putting in new code as I have been studying, Hopefully this is a clearer picture of what my goal is.

I want to go from a table based to a `div` setup, I have tried

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

with this CSS

```
div.image:before {
   content:url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
}
```

But I am unsure of the placement of the text, also putting an image in the `div` as well as making sure the dimension is correct.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>My Site</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
.bgimg {
    background-image: ('file:///C:/Location/somimg.jpg');
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="somimg.jpg" width="246" height="94" alt="sm pic'/>
<div class="bgimg">
</div>

<div class="mainsection">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
td {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:15px;
    color: #E5E5E5;
}

.div-with-bg
{
    width: 263px;
    height: 94px;
    background-image:url('smpic.jpg');
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:#9D5FBB;
}

A:Hover  {
    color : #DBACF2;
    text-decoration : underline;
}

h1 {
    color: #9929bd;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}

H3 {
    color: #7F409E;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size : 20px;
    font-family:Tahoma;
}
```

My goal is to have the div's go out to the edge of the browsers as I have multiple tables that I would like to replace with div elements. I have viewed this setup in a browser and the div and image show up but not at the edge of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand what you're asking but I just copied your HTML in Sublime text, and did this for css:

```
div.image:before {
    width: 263px;
    height: 94px;
    background-image:url('somepic.jpg');
    content:url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

It works for me. I have the left div on the left and the right div next to it.

Also, I would the the style of the divs in the css file:

```
div.right {
float: "middle"
}

div.left {
float: "left";
}
```

And for the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="image left">Left Div</div>
<div class="right"">Right Div</div>
</body>
```

And if you want to make your life easier just learn flexbox. The way i learned it was using [this](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) site.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
  <div>
  RIGHT
  </div>
</div>
```

This is one way to do it.

However i think that you should change the question into how i can learn to design in the browser (e.g. https://hackernoon.com/css-box-model-45ecf4ac219e) or something like that.